# Jersey framework resource response issue Chunked-Encoded data

Tags: java, http, docker, jersey, http-headers

I'm am developing an application with the Jersey framework that acts as a proxy to the docker HTTP API. I'm able to upload images successfully to Docker but I am unable to forward the response from Docker to the client without an error. I believe it has something to do with the Transfer-Encoding=[chunked] header in the response.

**Response**

```
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> POST /proxy/images/load HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/octet-stream
> Content-Length: 477637632
> Expect: 100-continue
> 
< HTTP/1.1 100 
< HTTP/1.1 200 
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Docker-Experimental: false
< Api-Version: 1.26
< Server: Docker/1.13.1 (linux)
< Date: Mon, 23 Jul 2018 11:20:14 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json
< Content-Length: 54
< 
* Problem (2) in the Chunked-Encoded data
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Problem (2) in the Chunked-Encoded data
```

**code**

```
@POST 
@Path("/load2")
//@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
public Response loadimages(byte[] input, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {             
    WebTarget webTarget = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("http://127.0.0.1:5555/images").path("load");    
    Response response   = webTarget.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.entity(input, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM));
    return response;
}
```